# jQuery on change of radio button update previous input value

Tags: jquery

I have multiple products on a page that contains a form with product info.

The default value of the product input is the name of the product, with the default - CD appended at the end. If a user selects 'Digital Download' I need to update the value of the product and swap '- CD' to '- Digital'.

I've made a rough jsfiddle with a slight variation to show the hidden inputs. You'll notice both inputs are changing when it should only be the input inside the product being selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ffh9bss/

cheers!

```
<div class="product">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input class="product-input" name="product" type="hidden" value="Cool music vol 1 - CD" />
        <label>Select format</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="CD" checked="checked">CD 
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Digital">Digital Download<br/>
        <input type="submit" class="product-buy" value="Buy now!" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input class="product-input" name="product" type="hidden" value="Cool music vol 2 - CD" />
        <label>Select format</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="CD" checked="checked">CD 
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Digital">Digital Download<br/>
        <input type="submit" class="product-buy" value="Buy now!" />
    </form>
</div>


$(".product").each(function() {
    $('input:radio').bind("change",updateFormat);

        function updateFormat(e){
            e.preventDefault();                     
            var $productValue = $('.product-input').val();
            var $productValueSplit = $productValue.split('-')[0];
            var $radioValue = $("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();

            console.log($productValueSplit + ' - ' + $radioValue);
        }
});
```

Comment: Im not sure if I construed your question correctly, but you can use `.attr()` to update value fields. Such as, `$('#yourProductField').attr("value", "theValueYouWantHere");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mate. I think I have successfully now updated the value to reflect what i want, but now my issue is that I can't do it just for the one product at a time. Any change to a radio button affects all products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like much the way you structure your **HTML**. It makes me do something funky to get what you want, but that's up to you. I'm able to achieve what you want with this code:

```
$('input:radio').each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        var ind = $(this).closest(".product").index();
        var $productValue = $('.product-input').eq(ind).val();
        var $productValueSplit = $productValue.split('-')[0];
        var $radioValue = $("form").eq(ind).find('input:checked').val();
        $('.product-input').eq(ind).val($productValueSplit + ' - ' + $radioValue);
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4ffh9bss/4/

Comment: Thanks so much Verhaeren! Unfortunately I can't change the markup, so am forced to use it as is.

Comment: @Rich It's find. Sometimes we just have to work with what they give us.